# TypeScript errors with Set type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 errors with a function that I have attempted to convert to TypeScript. The problem is with the parameters which are of type `Set`

```js
import type {Set} from 'typescript'

function union<T>(setA: Set<T>, setB: Set<T>) {
  const _union = new Set(setA);
  for (const elem of setB) {
    _union.add(elem)
  }
  return _union
}
```

The first error is on line 4: `new Set(setA)`

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.

The second error is on line 5: `for (const elem of setB)`

> TS2495: Type 'Set ' is not an array type or a string type.

Otherwise, this function works as expected.

tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["esnext"],
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: There's no need to explicitly import `Set` (or `Map` or other JavaScript standard library types), and [if you don't, it works just fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABOeYA8AVAfACgM4CmUAggFyIDKRmWANIoVAELlVQ0CUiA3gFCIDEEBHiiIA+igSIAvIjAEA7pSL4ixDgG5+g4HABOiHMLCjEBADYEAtojjAGRJlz6C3EqWAB0AQwAmfjiWNlo6AgC+YYj6RCD6SJJgqNrhQA). I have no idea why it doesn't work when you do what you're doing, but you don't need to do that, so...

Comment: Have you enabled *downleveliteration* (or whatever the configuration was called) that allows only iterating strings and arrays with `for … of`, not ES6 iterables?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [Not if you target ES5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?downlevelIteration=true&target=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3gZRTAvnAMyghDgHIlUBnAYymDBjIG4AoVggVwDsaZgI3ODwHcAPABUAfAAoqOAIIAuONhiSpAGjjyYAIRVqNASgys4FuDUFV4AfRGC4AXjjcUAd1U45i420tCaDgZa25bOBQAGxRSCAIdHD1TdHNAywduUQA6AEMAE3yZaNj-NItccrgoHE4oIUzRNlwgA), where that parameter actually comes into play

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for that tip. I've removed the import and that has resolved the constructor error.

Comment: @Bergi I haven't added *downlevelIteration*

Comment: @Dave Maybe you should though? I'm getting an error "*Type `Set<T>` can only be iterated through when using the `--downlevelIteration` flag or with a `--target` of `es2015` or higher.*" otherwise. Still, please [edit] your question to show us your *tsconfig* so that we can reproduce your problem, ideally on the online playground.

Comment: @Bergi I've added my tsconfig contents.

Comment: Well yes as I've guessed, you must not use `"target": "es5"` if you want to use native `Set`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Problem

When you `import { Set } from 'typescript'`, you actually import the type definition for the Set object.
Then, I believe, the type definition overlaps the Set object given by javascript(without the need to import it).
If you look for the `Set` type definition in `typescript`, you'll find out that `Set` represents a Typescript `interface`:

```
    interface Set<T> extends ReadonlySet<T>, Collection<T> {
        add(value: T): this;
        delete(value: T): boolean;
    }
```

But when you call `new Set()`, the interpreter looks for a constructor to initiate the object, but it doesn't find one, as the imported `Set` is an interface. And that is why you get the errors:

- `No overload matches this call.`: There is no constructor for the imported `Set`, so Typescript doesn't find any relevant function that could initiate the `Set`.
- `TS2495: Type 'Set ' is not an array type or a string type.`: `Set` is indeed not an array type, nor a string as it is an `interface`.

## The Solution

As javascript gives us the Set object, without any need to import it, you don't have to import it at all.
In addition, you also don't have to import the `Set` type definition, as it is built in.